# Who did Cersei mean by 'silver-haired bitch'?

Tags: game-of-thrones, character-motivation

In the Season 7 finale of Game of Thrones,

> Queen Cersei meets Daenerys, Jon Snow, and Tyrion to discuss the truce extended by Daenerys.

Just before she goes down to the Dragonpit, she gives the Mountain (Ser Gregor Clegane) a set of instructions:

> "If anything goes wrong, kill the silver-haired bitch first. Then our brother, then the bastard who calls himself King. The rest of them you can kill in any order you see fit."

So we know that number 2 was Tyrion, and number 3 was Jon Snow. But who was the first?

I know, it might seem obvious that she was talking about Daenerys. As a Targaryen, she is famous for the silver hair of her people. But I was reading [this](https://www.buzzfeed.com/andyneuenschwander/80-thoughts-i-had-watching-the-game-of-thrones-finale-this?utm_term=.eeY0gPP7a#.ix3b3DDK4) list and got a bit stuck at number 6. Could she possibly have been talking about Brienne of Tarth?

It's obvious that she has a bit of a thing against Brienne for being (maybe) in love with Jaime, as she accused her of during the Purple wedding. And later, the three of them exchange some very charged glances, centered on Jaime. Also, Cersei says "Noone walks away from me" which could mean she thinks Jaime might still feel something for Brienne.

Another thing. Jaime never blinked an eye when Cersei killed innocents and destroyed the Sept of Baelor. And this was after he stabbed the Mad King in the back for wanting to burn the entire city with wildfire, which was what Cersei used on the Sept of Baelor. She killed her daughter-in-law, father-in-law, cousin, betrothed and (indirectly) caused her son Tommen to commit suicide. But Jaime didn't have that much of a problem with the attack.

Here, she is telling the Mountain who to kill *if anything goes wrong*. Which means she had no plans to cause trouble at the meeting, but she had every suspicion that the others might (warranted, I guess for a not-so-beloved Queen). And she was telling the Mountain who to kill first, should something happen. Far less terrible than blowing up the Sept of Baelor. And yet Jaime looks so horrified/disgusted/disbelieving at this.

After his vow to cut Tyrion in half, I doubt he felt awful on his brother's behalf. And there's no reason for him to particularly care about Jon. So the only reason he could have strong feelings against what Cersei said was in regards to the 'silver-haired bitch". If it meant Daenerys, again not much reason for Jaime's reaction.

But Brienne's hair is almost exactly the same shade as Daenerys' (in the show at least). And if Jaime does have feelings for her, it might make him react that way.

I'm not asking for an opinion-based answer. I'm asking if there is any conclusive proof that Cersei was indeed talking about Daenerys, or otherwise. Leaked scripts, or comments from the producers or the actors themselves would be ideal.

Comment: She names the other two high lords at the conference... why would it be some "random" follower... Also, their hair color really is nothing alike.

Comment: It's obviously Daenerys' evil twin sister that will show up in the next season...

Comment: Has there been any scene where Cersei gives any sign of viewing Brienne as a love rival? The only scene I can think of where they even interact is Joffrey's wedding where I thought she seemed to laugh at Brienne's awkwardness? Didn't she even openly mock the idea that Brienne was naively in love with Jaime or have I got it mixed up?

Comment: I’m not going to DV because you’ve allowed yourself to be led astray by the source of this dumb question; the dumb Buzzfeed article. But it’s dumb. She was obviously talking about Daenerys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Brienne of Tarth is described as having **Straw Coloured Hair** in the books and blonde in the show to match. Daenerys is described as having **pale, Silver/Gold hair** as Targaryens are known to. Dany is also (in Cersei's eyes) the attempting usurper in charge of foreign armies and dragons. She is the literal closest and greatest threat to Cersei's rule and life, and the most likely person to be laying a trap at the meeting Dany requested.

So it's almost unequivocal that Cersei meant to kill Daenerys, her greatest threat, first.